# Plot multiple data frames as bar lines in the same figure

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create 5 line bars that show the frequency of these 5 different names in the same figure between the years 2018 and 2022.

```
Sophia = df_years[(df_years.Childs_First_Name == 'Sophia')]
df_Sophia = Sophia.groupby(['Year_of_Birth','Childs_First_Name'])['Count'].sum().reset_index().sort_values(by='Count', ascending=False).head(5)
df_Sophia

Isabella = df_years[(df_years.Childs_First_Name == 'Isabella')]
df_Isabella = Isabella.groupby(['Year_of_Birth','Childs_First_Name'])['Count'].sum().reset_index().sort_values(by='Count', ascending=False).head(5)
df_Isabella

Olivia = df_years[(df_years.Childs_First_Name == 'Olivia')]
df_Olivia = Olivia.groupby(['Year_of_Birth','Childs_First_Name'])['Count'].sum().reset_index().sort_values(by='Count', ascending=False).head(5)
df_Olivia

Emma = df_years[(df_years.Childs_First_Name == 'Emma')]
df_Emma = Emma.groupby(['Year_of_Birth','Childs_First_Name'])['Count'].sum().reset_index().sort_values(by='Count', ascending=False).head(5)
df_Emma

Mia = df_years[(df_years.Childs_First_Name == 'Mia')]
df_Mia = Mia.groupby(['Year_of_Birth','Childs_First_Name'])['Count'].sum().reset_index().sort_values(by='Count', ascending=False).head(5)
df_Mia
```

This is what I have for one:

How can I join these 5 data frames in the same figure?

```
df_Mia.plot( 'Year_of_Birth' , 'Count' )
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of your data?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to give you an answer since we don't know the structure of the input data and what you mean by the frequency of names.

Here is some code that:

- Generate random names and random birth dates as input data
- Create a bar plot of the count of the names you have specified for each year

```python
import random
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

first_names = [
    "Alexandra",
    "Alice",
    "Angelica",
    "Sophia",
    "Isabella",
    "Olivia",
    "Emma",
    "Mia",
    "Martina",
    "Claudia",
    "Gladys",
    "Priscilla",
    "Gabriella",
    "Francesca",
    "Laura"
]

last_names = [
    "Barbieri",
    "Costa",
    "Pellegrino",
    "Robustelli",
    "Leone",
    "Romano",
    "Vinci",
    "Gentile",
    "Ballerini",
    "Mancini",
    "Moretti",
    "Pavone",
    "Donatelli",
    "Amato",
    "Argento",
    "Bernardi",
    "Guerra"
]

population_size = 10000

birth_records = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Childs_First_Name": random.choices(first_names, k=population_size),
        "Childs_Last_Name": random.choices(last_names, k=population_size),
        "Year_of_Birth": (random.randint(2018, 2022) for _ in range(population_size))
    }
)

births_per_year_per_name = birth_records.groupby(['Year_of_Birth', 'Childs_First_Name']).count().reset_index()

births_per_year_per_name.rename(columns={
    'Childs_Last_Name': 'Count', 
    "Childs_First_Name": "First Name"
    },
    inplace=True
)

births_per_year = births_per_year_per_name.pivot(index='Year_of_Birth', columns='First Name', values='Count')

first_names_to_keep = ['Sophia', 'Isabella', 'Olivia', 'Emma', 'Mia']

births_per_year_filtered = births_per_year[first_names_to_keep]

_, ax = plt.subplots()

births_per_year_filtered.plot(
    ax=ax,
    kind='bar',
    ylabel="Count",
    xlabel="Year of Birth"
)

plt.show()
```

If this is not what you are looking for, can you refine your question and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?